# Story where a monster asks if he has a soul

Tags: story-identification, magic, souls

I'd like to know the name of a book written no more recent than the year 2000 (probably a bit older.) It includes only two themes that I can recall:

- The main character is exiled for not having a magical power in a world where everyone else has a single magical power. (At the conclusion of this book it is determined that the main character's magical power is immunity to the magical powers of others.)
- A monster asks a wizard who answers a single question per individual whether he has a soul or not and is told that if he is asking that question, he does have a soul.  The monster is then tasked with guarding the wizards tower.

I believe this book is part of a series.  Can anyone identify it?

Comment: Not your story, but reminds me of the SAL-9000 in _2010_ asking Dr. Chandra "Will I dream?", and Dr. Chandra's response.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[*A Spell for Chameleon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Spell_for_Chameleon), the first book of the *Xanth* series by Piers Anthony, is probably the book you want.

> “What question did you bring?” Bink inquired somewhat nervously,
>   trying not to brace himself too obviously for flight. In an open
>   space, he was no possible match for the manticora.
>
> “I asked whether I have a soul,” the monster said seriously.

Comment: Well done. You beat me to it by 10 seconds :-P

Comment: I new it instantly as well :)

Comment: Could you please add the name of the author and series title to the answer to make searching easier in the future?

Comment: @b_jonas: Will do :).