# Seeking a YA fantasy about a person with no magic in a land where everyone else has magic

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, magic

I'm looking for a book about a kid that lives in a world where everyone has magic but he does not. Later in the book, he finds out his magic is just hidden and shows up in the form of luck. This was a series of books I remember were comedy fantasy.  Later in the series he travels to another world that doesn't have magic through a portal (it's our world).

I remember that the start of the book was intentionally tropey and there is something about a lizard sitting on a rock? The details are hazy. I checked it out from my high school library in 2002, so it had to be older than that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are thinking of the [Xanth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanth) series by Piers Anthony, and in particular, the first book, *[A Spell for Chameleon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Spell_for_Chameleon)* - these predate Y2K considerably (1977 for the first one) but the series was still being added to then (and in fact is still being added to now). The main character of the first book, Bink, is condemned to exile, because he has no magic, but it turns out his magic is powerful, but subtle - he can not be harmed by magic, which results in many narrow escapes, apparently by luck. There are many puns in the book, and the general tone is humorous, so I think it's fair to call these "comedy/fantasy."

There is travel to the world without magic in these books - that world is called "Mundania" - and is our world.

Here's the cover of the first book:

[image: The cover of "A Spell for Chameleon" by Piers Anothony. The cover shows Bink talking to a manticore outside of a gate.]

Comment: This would be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71132/story-where-a-monster-asks-if-he-has-a-soul/71133#71133

Comment: "and there is something about a lizard sitting on a rock?" -- that's confirmation; Bink sees that, early on, and it's a reference to Chameleon, who he would meet later.

Comment: Thanks  - I forgot that

Comment: You all are awesome! This is it thank you.